# Is it possible to connect dekstop sql server and vps sql server & migrate data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my laptop & I have SQL Server 2008 R2 vps hosting. I want to connect SQL Server on my laptop and in VPS, and migrate data from laptop to online server. How can I do it? Do I have to write code or is there any third party tool to do it? Is their any process to do it easily?

Comment: The SSMS Import and Export wizard is pretty easy to use to copy data between tables if that's all you are doing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Plenty of ways; you can use the Import/Export wizard tool, the Copy Database tool, SSIS, or even BCP from the command line.

Comment: @JacobH i am trying to migrate laptop server database to vps server database. I just synchronize database in every few minutes so that i can migrate data to online server. Their will be changes on laptop server database and their won't be any changes on online database. All i want is to make database to migrate in every few minutes difference.

Comment: That "all I want" is database replication. BTW the earliest supported SQL Server version is 2012. Replication differs from one version to another and obviously gets better with each new edition. SQL Server 2016 SP1 offers for free, in all editions,  features that were only available with Enterprise back in 2010